# Как дискорд-боту "стримить" аудио с Яндекс.Музыки?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно воспроизводить трек с Яндекс.Музыки без скачивания самого трека.

Возможно ли так сделать, если возможно то как? Использую библиотеки yandex_music, discord.py и FFMPEG для воспроизведения аудио

Сейчас всё работает следующим образом: бот скачивает трек - воспроизводит - удаляет прошлый трек если скачивается новый трек.
Код:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    if os.path.exists("as") == True:
        os.remove("as")
        if ctx.message.content.startswith('!play'):
            channel = ctx.message.channel
            music.download(ctx.message.content[5:].format(ctx.message))

        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if not channel:
            await ctx.send("Вы не подключены к голосовому чату :(")
            return
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('as')
        player = voice.play(source)
    else:
        if ctx.message.content.startswith('!play'):
            channel = ctx.message.channel
            music.download(ctx.message.content[5:].format(ctx.message))
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if not channel:
            await ctx.send("Вы не подключены к голосовому чату :(")
            return
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('as')
        player = voice.play(source)
```

Answer (score -1):

Выдает ошибку `as: No such file or directory`

Вот код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    if os.path.exists("as") == True:
        os.remove("as")
        if ctx.message.content.startswith('!play'):
            channel = ctx.message.channel
            music.download(ctx.message.content[5:].format(ctx.message))

        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if not channel:
            await ctx.send("Вы не подключены к голосовому чату :(")
            return
        voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('as')
        player = voice.play(source)
    else:
        if ctx.message.content.startswith('!play'):
            channel = ctx.message.channel
            music.download(ctx.message.content[5:].format(ctx.message))
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        if not channel:
            await ctx.send("Вы не подключены к голосовому чату :(")
            return
        voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('as', executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe")
        player = voice.play(source)
```

Comment: это ответ или новый вопрос?